# "Show all windows" macos dock icon giving error

Tags: macos, qt5, dock, qapplication

I have Qt application running on macos. There to be consistent to MacOS general behaviour when window is closed app is still running.

However when I do that, if I click on Dock icon option "Show all windows" it says "No windows available".

How can I fix that I have not found doc about this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at following AppDelegate methods. They do what you need. - (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender;
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag;

Comment: Is possible to integrate that into QApplication?? (mine is QApp)

Comment: I just know how to handle that in Cocoa. Google or see code on github.